# Is there way to make not UI Unit test in Windows 10 (UWP) project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-10-universal

Universal Windows Platform Applications has Unit test project, but it run tests veeeeeeery slow. I think it's because of Xaml UI Tests. Does anybody know the way to disable UI testing in Unit Tests?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the same thing. I haven't found a way either, but in the xaml.cs file you can see `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.UnitTestClient.Run(e.Arguments);`. Maybe there is a way to convert the project to a non-UI test project and call that from `main()` or so...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't...

I understand as I was also looking into this. I had a simple Class Library and all I wanted was a **simple** Unit Test project!

Perhaps we'll see one in later updates of Visual Studio.